Не получается установить шрифт в CustomTkinter
начал учить CustomTkinter, и решил импортировать скачанный шрифт в программу
import customtkinter as ctk

class APP(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.title("First Program")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        ctk.FontManager.load_font(r"resources\fonts\Comfortaa-Bold.ttf")
        self.entry_phone = ctk.CTkEntry(master=self, placeholder_text=" Введите номер", width=153, height=50,  font=("Comfortaa-Bold", 18))
        self.entry_phone.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=190, pady=420, sticky="nsew")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = APP()
    app.mainloop()

но почему-то шрифт остается стандартным, и никак не меняется

шрифт должен быть таким

но он такой
Что делать?
